# Draw transmission line circuits

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

This is an example of a transmission line circuit:

[image]

(Another one is available [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/images/appnotes/5432/5432Fig01.gif)). Transmission lines are conventionally drawn with two horizontal, parallel cylinders, with variable, adaptable length. I didn't find anything similar in `circuitikz`. In the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) (page 8), a single `transmission line stub` is provided, but it is a small, single cylinder with fixed length.

How to draw the above example circuit with `circuitikz` or `tikz`?

Answer (score 4):

How about this? I edited the original version of the `tline` drawer to make the cylinder have length determined by the length of the line segment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}{tline}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/width}}
{   
    %% First find distance from startpoint to endpoint
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}start}{center}}
                 {\pgfpointanchor{\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}end}{center}}
    \pgfmathparse{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}
    %% The coordinate system has been changed so that the origin is at the midpoint and
    %% the line is along the x axis. So shift back by half the length of the line, and 
    %% make the cylinder of width roughly the length of the line, with a 40pt setback
    %% on each side.
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgfmathresult/2-30pt}
    \pgf@circ@res@left=\dimexpr-\pgfmathresult pt+40pt\relax
    %% Here is the original function, copied directly from the source of circuittikz, 
    %% down to next %%
    \pgf@circ@res@step=.2\pgf@circ@res@right % half x axis
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{0}}
                   {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0}}
                   {\pgfpoint{0}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{-\pgf@circ@res@step and -\pgf@circ@res@up}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    %% I have to fill the figure to block out the original line
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfusepath{draw,fill}
    %% Redraw part of the line that gets blocked by the cylinder by mistake
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-2*\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[TL] (10,0) to[TL] (14,4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of effort!

Comment: I agree, it's a huge work and thank you anyway to Hood. But the example doesn't consider the cylinders as a "couple": they are treated separately, and they are not parallel. Maybe this is left to the user?

Comment: It could be very troublesome to define and handle two cylinders separately for every line.

Comment: @BowPark Can you elaborate on the issue you are having?

Comment: @HoodChatham Sorry, I can't understand your question: can you rephrase it?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by this? "But the example doesn't consider the cylinders as a 'couple': they are treated separately, and they are not parallel." If you give me some code that demonstrates the undesirable result, I can probably fix it for you.

Comment: @HoodChatham Ok! For example, [this](https://imgur.com/3YgUpgq) is the output of your code. Unlike in the image I posted in the question, the cylinders are not a couple: they are two independent shapes. Between `(0,0)` and `(10,0)` there should not be a single cylinder, but a couple of cylinders (with a fixed spacing between them).

Comment: Oh, yeah I think you should do that by hand (unless you have a pretty good reason not to?) To draw two parallel cylinders you can try for instance:
`\draw (0,-2) -- (0,0) (10,-2) -- (10,0)
    foreach \y in {0,-2} {[yshift=\y cm] (0,0) to[TL] (10,0)};`

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else needs this, I modified Hood's solution (just changed drawing order, line thicknesses) to make the ends of the transmission line look like the original ones. Here is my result:

[image: transmission line circuit]

And the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}{tline}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/height}}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/tline/width}}
{   
    %% First find distance from startpoint to endpoint
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}start}{center}}
                 {\pgfpointanchor{\ctikzvalof{bipole/name}end}{center}}
    \pgfmathparse{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}
    %% The coordinate system has been changed so that the origin is at the midpoint and
    %% the line is along the x axis. So shift back by half the length of the line, and 
    %% make the cylinder of width roughly the length of the line, with a 40pt setback
    %% on each side.
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgfmathresult/2-30pt}
    \pgf@circ@res@left=\dimexpr-\pgfmathresult pt+40pt\relax

    %% Here is the original function, copied directly from the source of circuittikz, 
    %% down to next %%
    \pgf@circ@res@step=.2\pgf@circ@res@right % half x axis
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{-\pgf@circ@res@step and -\pgf@circ@res@up}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfusepath{draw,fill}

    %% I have to fill the figure to block out the original line
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgf@circ@res@step}{0}}
                   {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0}}
                   {\pgfpoint{0}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfusepath{draw, fill}

    %% Redraw part of the line that gets blocked by the cylinder by mistake
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-1*\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[TL] (10,0) to[TL] (14,4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```