# Transmission Line as a Quadrupole in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

How do I realize a circuit with a trasmission line as a quadrupole (quadripole?) like the one in the picture (from Wikipedia)?

[image]

The standard versione is just a single cylinder which means I would have to do something like done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402631/draw-transmission-line-circuits), which is not ideal since I think is "too abstract" for my purpose and doesn't really represent the situation I'm studying.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that you do not  want a symbolic circuit, but something which is a mix between a drawing (better done with pure TikZ) and a circuit. I propose to split the things; after all, a `circuitikz` is also a `tikzpicture`. Like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc}
%\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    % this is a cylinder with an axial line
    \node [cylinder, draw, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=1cm, xscale=-1](CYL){};
    \draw [gray, dashed] (CYL.before bottom) arc(270:90:0.125cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw [gray] (CYL.west) -- (CYL.east);
    \coordinate (CYL top center) at ($(CYL.before top)!0.5!(CYL.after top)$);
    \coordinate (CYL bottom center) at ($(CYL.before bottom)!0.5!(CYL.after bottom)$);
    \node [color=gray, circ] at (CYL bottom center) {};
    \node [circ] at (CYL top center) {};
    % these are the connections, almost simmetrical
    \draw (CYL top center) -- ++(-0.5,0) coordinate(top hot);
    \draw (CYL.west) -- ++(0.5,0) coordinate(bottom hot);
    \draw (CYL.after top) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate(tmp) -- (tmp -| top hot) coordinate(top shield);
    \draw (CYL.before bottom) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate(tmp) -- (tmp -| bottom hot) coordinate (bottom shield);
    % and then you add  the circuit
    \draw (top hot) to [R, o-] ++(-2,0) to[sV] ++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){};
    \draw (GND) to[short, *-] (GND-|top shield) to[short, -o] (top shield);
    \draw (bottom hot) to[short, o-] ++(1,0) to[R] ++(0,-2) -| (bottom shield) node[ocirc]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: picture of a transmission line]

You can find the details about the `cylinder` shape in the section dedicated to the "shape" library of the TikZ manual, and about the gimmick for the terminals, look at section 4.6 of the `circuitikz` manual, a recent version).

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! Now I've just got to understand to code a little bit better in order to use it in other circuits.